# Apache NIFI bidirectional TCP

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm doing a integration effort with Apache NIFI where we have stumbled upon the need to do bidirectional TCP. Before we have gotten away with only using unidirectional TCP.

Apache NIFI supports undirectional TCP through features such as 'ListenTCP' and 'PutTCP'. Bidirectional TCP is supported in the HTTP and websocket domain through features such as 'HandleHttpRequest', 'HandleHttpResponse', 'ConnectWebSocket', 'ListenWebSocket', and 'PutWebSocket'. A pure bidirectional TCP mechanic does not look evident.

Normaly I would dive into this with Python, Servicemix or .. whatever .. but in this case we need the magic of NIFI in the middle.

(Legacy product A) - TCP-  NIFI (NIFI Magic) -TCP- (Legacy product B)

So..

I'm considering taking the above NIFI liberies that do support TCP and the extra domains, and ripping them down to TCP only. Creating dedicated TCP modules. I'm assuming that would be better than starting to write this from scratch.

But before I do that. 
Is there something I'm missing?

1) Does NIFI have bidirectional TCP support that I'm missing somehow?

2) If no on 1.. is the above plan reasonable?

Thanks

K

Comment: `ListenTCP` and `PutTCP` has one direction functionality. as for me, to handle TCP request/response you have to look how it's done for `HandleHttpRequest` & `HandleHttpResponse` and repeat the same but with TCP.

Answer (score 1):

If you're comfortable writing TCP handlers using Python, you can use the [`ExecuteScript`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-scripting-nar/1.3.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.script.ExecuteScript/index.html) or [`InvokeScriptedProcessor`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-scripting-nar/1.3.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.script.InvokeScriptedProcessor/index.html) components to run arbitrary script (Python, Groovy, Ruby, Lua, Javascript, and Clojure) within the processor lifecycle that Apache NiFi supports. With this method, you can perform TCP bidirectional communication in a processor, route the data to other NiFi components, and then route it to another scripted processor where you perform more bidirectional TCP communication.